# Aligning my block text on html using css

Tags: html, css

So I am working on my simple project and I want to align my blocks horizontally to fit the screen, how do I do this in CSS or HTML?

My jsp code: how can I make them fit? Thanks very much, I tried but I don't want to remove my borders

I have tried some of the suggested answers from previous post but they keep changing my borders

```css
html,
body,
div,
h1,
li {
  border: 12px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ecf9fe;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  max-width: 200%;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content1 {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content2 {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}

.intro {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.information {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: Roboto Slab, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HotelMenuItem.css">
    <title>My Restaurant</title>
  </head>

  <body id="main" class="gradient">

    <h1 class="title shadow">MAMA RESTAURANT</h1>

    <div class="content shadow">
      <div>

        <p>Menu Item</p>
        <ul class="listing">
          <li>Appetizer</li>
          <li>Salad</li>
          <li>Mushroom</li>
          <li>pizaa</li>
          <li>Mozerello</li>
          <li>Rice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="content1 shadow">
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <p>Restaurant Items</p>
        <ul class="listing">

          <li> Diet Coke </li>
          <li> Heineken </li>
          <li>Jack Daniels</li>
          <li>Mango</li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2 shadow">
      <p>Favorite</p>
      <ul class="listing">

        <li> Food </li>
        <li> Food </li>
        <li>Food </li>
        <li>Food</li>

      </ul>

    </div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: do you mean that they grow on width? maybe 80% of screen width?

Comment: I want them to fit horizontally like 1 2 3 instead of going down 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are expecting. If not, please comment a little more on the problem if needed.

```css
html,
body,
div,
h1,
li {
  border: 12px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ecf9fe;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  max-width: 200%;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content1 {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content2 {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}

.intro {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.information {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: Roboto Slab, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33vw - 76px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 200px;
}

.big-box {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HotelMenuItem.css">
    <title>My Restaurant</title>
  </head>

  <body id="main" class="gradient">

    <h1 class="title shadow">MAMA RESTAURANT</h1>
    <div class="big-box">
      <div class="content shadow box">
        <div>
          <p>Menu Item</p>
          <ul class="listing">
            <li>Appetizer</li>
            <li>Salad</li>
            <li>Mushroom</li>
            <li>pizaa</li>
            <li>Mozerello</li>
            <li>Rice</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content1 shadow box">
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <p>Restaurant Items</p>
          <ul class="listing">
            <li> Diet Coke </li>
            <li> Heineken </li>
            <li>Jack Daniels</li>
            <li>Mango</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content2 shadow box">
        <p>Favorite</p>
        <ul class="listing">
          <li> Food </li>
          <li> Food </li>
          <li>Food </li>
          <li>Food</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: @Leonard happy to help

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using flex-box. I put the 3 columns into a content-wrapper.

```
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Also removed the width from the body and added to the columns instead.

Here is the full code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xb132cqc/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. I wrapped your "boxes" in a div with the class `center-wrapper` and added the following CSS for that class:

```
.center-wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

I also removed the `max-width` of `body` and its margins. Let me know if I've understood your question correctly. Your code is edited below.

```css
html,
body,
div,
h1,
li {
  border: 12px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ecf9fe;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  max-width: 200%;
  text-align: left;
}

.center-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.content {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content1 {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content2 {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 7px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}

.intro {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.information {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed, sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: Roboto Slab, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HotelMenuItem.css">
    <title>My Restaurant</title>
  </head>

  <body id="main" class="gradient">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
      <h1 class="title shadow">MAMA RESTAURANT</h1>

      <div class="content shadow">
        <div>

          <p>Menu Item</p>
          <ul class="listing">
            <li>Appetizer</li>
            <li>Salad</li>
            <li>Mushroom</li>
            <li>pizaa</li>
            <li>Mozerello</li>
            <li>Rice</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="content1 shadow">
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <p>Restaurant Items</p>
          <ul class="listing">

            <li> Diet Coke </li>
            <li> Heineken </li>
            <li>Jack Daniels</li>
            <li>Mango</li>

          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content2 shadow">
        <p>Favorite</p>
        <ul class="listing">

          <li> Food </li>
          <li> Food </li>
          <li>Food </li>
          <li>Food</li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this but i would want them to follow each other like 1 2 3 ... my English is not good. But i don't want them going down straight. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 3 `<div class="content shadow>` in a div.

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="content shadow">
    <div class="content1 shadow">
    <div class="content2 shadow">
</div>
```

After that, just add this css:

```
.boxes {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```